# Case-insensitive ordering using Hibernate Criteria

Tags: java, hibernate, sorting, criteria, case-insensitive

I have a query created with Hibernate Criteria like this:

```
Criteria criteria = db.getSession().createCriteria(Vendor.class);
criteria.addOrder(Property.forName("shortName").asc());
List<Vendor> vendorList = criteria.list();
```

I would like the ordering to be case-insensitive, equivalent to the HQL query

```
FROM Vendor ve ORDER BY lower(ve.shortName)
```

How can I achieve this using Hibernate Criteria?

Answer (score 25, accepted):

```
criteria.addOrder(Order.asc("shortName").ignoreCase());
```